# Pip using system python osx

Tags: python, macos, package, macports, pip

I installed python26 using macports, so the correct python on my system is `/opt/local/bin/python`

However, when I do

```
sudo pip install <packagename>
```

It gives me

```
sudo pip install <somepackage>                                           
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.0.1-py2.6.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.0.1-py2.6.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 215, in run
    import setuptools
ImportError: No module named setuptools

Storing complete log in /Users/navin/.pip/pip.log
```

And so, I suspect that it is using the system python. I've installed distribute (which contains setuptools) via their site instructions. I installed pip via an installer as well. I somehow managed to clobber the setuptools for the system python I think, so that's why I'm having this problem now :(

What do I do to get pip working again?

Comment: as it turns out I also installed pip via macports but the script-installed one takes precedence. I think removing my script-installed pip will fix the problem but I dont know how!

Comment: What's the output from `which pip` and `echo $PATH`?

Comment: /Users/navin/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/navin/code/jruby/bin:/Users/navin/.bin:/Users/navin/.ec2/bin:/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion:/Users/navin/.rvm/bin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove pip from /usr/local/bin with `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip`.

If you have installed pip with macports, `which pip` should then show `/opt/local/bin/pip`. If not, install pip again by following the instructions [here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html). As long as `which python` shows the `/opt/local` installation, it should work. If it *doesn't*, you will need to edit your `PATH` env variable.

Answer (score 14):

**UPDATE**: I strongly recommend installing CPython by building from source ([example](https://github.com/johnyf/env/blob/main/install_python.sh)), and then creating virtual environments to work in.

---

Summarizing the above, installing `pip` using Macports:

```sh
sudo port install py39-pip
```

results in an installation of a MacPorts port named `py39-pip`.

However, no `/opt/local/bin/pip` is installed and `port select pip` or `port select py27-pip` both fail (in contrast to `port select python`). Changing things in the `bin` directory of another distribution is not recommended.

Note that Python files in:

- `/usr/bin` are of the preinstalled Python of macOS
- `/usr/local/bin` are installed by MacPython, available from [python.org](http://www.python.org)
- `/opt/local/bin` are installed by MacPorts.

The actual executable files can be found by `ls -ls` applied to the various Python-related symbolic links found in each of the above `bin` directories).

To ensure that the Python installed by MacPorts is called first, place `/opt/local/bin` within the [runtime environment's `PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) earlier than `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`. This can be done in the file `~/.bash_profile` or the file `~/.bashrc` (which one depends on your system and configuration). For example, writing

```sh
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

last in `~/.bashrc` will have this effect (assuming that the intended shell will source the file `~/.bashrc`).

After the paths have been appropriately defined, the system still fails to find a `pip` command in the Macports `bin` directory, because it is installed as `/opt/local/bin/pip3.9`. The file `/opt/local/bin/pip` is not automatically created.

As a result, the system continues searching the `PATH`, and if e.g. MacPython is added to the path some place later and has `pip` installed, then that `pip` will show up.

This can be avoided by the command proposed above:

```sh
sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/pip3.9 /opt/local/bin/pip
```

Comment: Using Macports 2.3.1 & the following now works `sudo port select --set pip pip27`

Answer (score 3):

Here is my setup to get pip working with macports and set py26-pip as the default pip

```
sudo port install py26-pip && sudo port select --set pip py26-pip
```

after install finishes run to see the help information for pip

```
pip --help
```

after you may need to update your path to include the bin files installed by pip edit .bash_profile to include something like

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: My Python `bin` was located in `~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/`

Answer (score 1):

You should have the python and pip installed in /opt/local/bin/ prior to those installed in /usr/local/bin/.

Also, you should check to execute `which python` and whether the pip was installed in /opt/local/bin/pip.

Answer (score 0):

I found I needed to `ln -s /opt/local/bin/pip-2.7 /opt/local/bin/pip`. For some reason macports didn't built that link, even when you try activating that version of python or pip.